# What electronic component can send pulses?

Tags: voltage, frequency, pulse, hardware, synthesis

In analog hardware synthesizers, an electric pulse is sent by an oscillator to a sound-emitting device for it to create sound at the desired frequency.

- What device generates this pulse?
- What is the standard schematic symbol for this electronic component?

Comment: Any digital output can be either high or low. And switch between them, making a "pulse".

Comment: oscillators produce AC signal from DC source so i am not sure if this question makes any sense

Comment: There is no single component that generates pulses; there are numerous ways of doing so.

Comment: Maybe this question makes more sense if we interpret "electric pulse" to mean some arbitrary AC signal and oscillator to be some waveform generator. A switch would do.

Comment: It would probably be more accurate to say that an electronic *signal* is sent from an oscillator to a sound-emitting device. There are too many kinds of oscillators for us to be able to describe them all, but Wikipedia describes several kinds: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_oscillator

Comment: I offered to change "hardware synthesizer" to "electronic music synthesizer" to avoid confusion with software tools that EEs use to design electronic hardware. The process of realizing a hardware design is sometimes known as "synthesis."

Comment: Sounds like the op might be interested in a "signal" or "waveform" rather than "pulse".

Comment: @EugeneSh., Exactly! A "signal" is continuous, a "pulse" is a one-time event. An oscillator generates a continuous signal.

Comment: Re, "What device generates this [signal]?" The oscillator generates it.

Comment: Re "What is the standard schematic symbol for this electronic component?" An oscillator is not a component. It's a "module" or a "subsystem." If the oscillator is contained within an integrated circuit module, then it would appear on a schematic using a similar symbol to any other IC. Otherwise, the components _of_ the oscillator would appear individually as separate components in the diagram. An oscillator probably would be represented in a higher-level _block diagram_ as a box with the word "oscillator" on it.

Comment: @SolomonSlow A Digital Sampling Synthesizer  is a digital to analog component commonly used to generate waveform, a music synth is something entirely different. I'm not sure which we are talking about so I rolled the edit back.

Comment: @Tanner Swett Interesting... Thank you for that article.

Comment: @Voltage Spike I'm talking about a music synth, yes. Excuse me for the lack of precision...

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Ah, yes. That's true. I wasn't aware of that until you made me realise that a pulse is a single event. Sorry for my misconception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These circuits can vary and there is no specific single component , electrically, that can be pointed to as the "output", it is usually a circuit, which might be integrated into an IC or other device.

Quoting from another answer of mine on an unrelated question https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/550721/1729

> It is important to understand, ahead of time, what your work product is trying to communicate, an electrical design consists of many different documents and deliverables. A schematic as a design asset needs to be specific as possible. It is simultaneously defining the implementation and serves as a documentation for other designers. In extreme cases some professional shops go as far as define a symbol for every part number. A simplified schematic has a different use case (publication in academic paper) than a production worthy schematic.

If you are making certain types of system diagrams it is ok to use generic symbols for various elements. With the knowledge that they convey incomplete information.

For example a pulse source can be  pulse square wave inside a circle. Generally a symbol inside a circle is indicating to a reader that there is more complexity inside the device.

Comment: This answers my question. You need a whole circuit rather than an electronic component. Thank you so much for your precision on that.

Comment: Oh, just found something... How about a crystal oscillator? Seems to be globally recognised as a single component. Is it possible that such a device be used as an oscillation generator for music synthesisers? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_oscillator

Comment: Naked XO's are almost never seen providing unprotected output, it still needs a circuit, e.g. an amplifier or a buffer to use as a synth worthy output.

Comment: I see. Very interesting. Thank you!